# In flask i am not able fetch the session variables from the facebook messenger

Tags: python-3.x, flask, facebook-messenger-bot, flask-session

I am using flask session to achieve multi-user concurrency in my chatbot which is embedded in FB messenger and backend implemented in python.

Below is code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def webhook():

    state = session.get('state')
    session.modified = True
    print("state:",state)
    q_number = session.get('q_number')
    age = session.get('age')
    print('age:',age)
    sex = session.get('sex')
    symptoms = session.get('symptoms', []) 
    prev = session.get('prev')
    conditions = session.get('conditions')

    data = request.get_json()
    ##pprint(data["entry"])

    sender_id  = data["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["sender"]["id"]

    # get user info
    r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/'+sender_id+
        '?fields=first_name,last_name&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN)

    if data["object"] == "page":

        user_input = data['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']
        #print(type(user_input))
        user_input = user_input.lower()
    #print(user_input)

    question = get_question(sender_id,user_input,state, q_number, age, sex, symptoms, prev, conditions)

    send_message(sender_id, question)
    return "ok", 200
```

session.get is not working in flask and i am unable to fetch the values. so i cant able to send the state,age,sex,q_number,symptoms,prev,conditions to other function.. Please help me to overcome this.

Comment: Check this link https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but calling `requests.get` in a route function like this will lead to misc problems in production, as this will hang the whole worker while that function takes an undefined ammount of time to complete.  The correct way to implement this is with something like [rq](http://python-rq.org/) - in their example the `count_words` function is where the `requests` call goes.  As for the conn error, have you actually started a redis server on localhost?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SakthiPanneerselvam.. I tried using 'redis', but it is giving exception :"TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "